# How to cut desired level of unlimited depth of JSON data in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have a large JSON file with the following structure, with different depth embedded in a node. I want to delete different levels based on assigned depth.

So far I tried to cut some level manually but still it doesn't remove correctly as I remove them based on index and each time indexes shift

```
content = json.load(file)
content_copy = content.copy()
for j, i in enumerate(content):
    if 'children' in i:
        for xx, x in enumerate(i['children']):
            if 'children' in x:
                for zz, z in enumerate(x['children']):
                    if 'children' in z:
                        del content_copy[j]['children'][xx]['children'][zz]
```

**Input:**

```
[
   {
      "name":"1",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"3",
            "children":"5"
         },
         {
            "name":"33",
            "children":"51"
         },
         {
            "name":"13",
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"20",
                  "children":"30"
               },
               {
                  "name":"40",
                  "children":"50"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"2",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"7",
            "children":"6"
         },
         {
            "name":"3",
            "children":"521"
         },
         {
            "name":"193",
            "children":"292"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**Output:**
In which in 'name':13, its children were removed.

```
     [
    {
        "name": "1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "3",
                "children": "5"
            },
            {
                "name": "33",
                "children": "51"
            },
            {
                "name": "13"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "2",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "7",
                "children": "6"
            },
            {
                "name": "3",
                "children": "521"
            },
            {
                "name": "193",
                "children": "292"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You may want to copy the desired nodes as you find them. Do you just want to delete grandchildren?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove all the children/grandschildren on a specific level. I guess it can happen through implementing it in a function e.g. pruneJson(json, level) so that the function be embedded inside itself but so far I couldn't implement myself. so to loop until it reaches a level and cut them.

Comment: You want to prune children lists, but keep children strings, looks like. Why keep the only children but prune the lists at the same depth? My answer matches OP as is, but I do have some concern about that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to prune is pass depth+1 in a recursive function call.

You are asking for different behaviors for different types. If the grandchild is just a string, you want to keep it, but if it is a list then you want to prune. This seems inconsistent, 13 should have children ["20", "30"] but then they wouldn't be the same node structure, so I can see your dilemma.

I would convent them to a tree of node objects, and then just prune nodes, but to get the exact output you listed, I can just selectively prune based on whether child is a string or list.

```
import pprint
import json

data = """[{
 "name": "1", "children":
 [
   {"name":"3","children":"5"},{"name":"33","children":"51"}, 
 {"name":"13","children":[{"name":"20","children":"30"}, 
 {"name":"40","children":"50"}]}
 ]
},
{
  "name": "2", "children":
  [
    {"name":"7","children":"6"},
    {"name":"3","children":"521"}, 
   {"name":"193","children":"292"}
  ]
 }]"""

content = json.loads(data)

def pruned_nodecopy(content, prune_level, depth=0):
    if not isinstance(content, list):
        return content

    result = []
    for node in content:
        node_copy = {'name': node['name']}

        if 'children' in node:
            children = node['children']
            if not isinstance(children, list):
                node_copy['children'] = children
            elif depth+1 < prune_level:
                node_copy['children'] = pruned_nodecopy(node['children'], prune_level, depth+1)

        result.append(node_copy)
    return result            

content_copy = pruned_nodecopy(content, 2)                        
pprint.pprint (content_copy)
```

Note that this is specifically copying the attributes you use. I had to make it use hard-coded attributes because you're asking for specific (and different) behaviors on those.

Comment: Thanks. It seems working and I am going to test it more. But one error I came up with, I found nodes without Children so I added an if statement before this line "for node in content", The if statement is if 'children' in content... so this will not confuse your code? will the nodes without chidlren won't be touched?

Comment: That seems like the wrong place to put that check. sec

Comment: Again, I'm giving you the specific output you requested. This is NOT pruning children at a certain level. Can you clarify if that was an error in the original question, or if this is really what you want?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't prune at a certain level? The question is at an assigned certain level, the children should be removed for all the nodes at that level. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Myl goal was to demonstrate a depth parameter in a recursive call, so I'm happy with that.

Comment: Notice that 1 has children [3, 33, 13] and 3 has children [5] and 13 has children [20, 40]. We keep 1.3.5 because it's just a string, but we prune 1.13.20 and 1.13.40 because they have substructure. But really 5, 20 and 40 are all at the same depth but with different representation. I was careful this time to give you exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Not a python answer, but in the hope it's useful to someone, here is a one liner using [jq tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
<file jq 'del(.[][][]?[]?[]?)'
```

It simply deletes all elements that has a depth more than the 5.

The question mark `?` is used to avoid iterating over elements that would have a depth less than 3.

Comment: Thanks. It is useful indeed.